# Powershel Sum Duration Values

Tags: powershell

I have created a `[pscustomobject]` with only the properties i'm interested in. Now I need to sum some values that represent time. I'm trying but, returns nothing. I'm Doing something wrong, but can't figure it out.

```
 function Convert-TimeString ([String]$Time, [String[]]$Format)
 {
  $result = New-Object TimeSpan

  $convertible = [TimeSpan]::TryParseExact(
  $Time,
  $Format,
  [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture,
  [ref]$result)

  if ($convertible) { $result.ToString('hh\:mm\:ss\.fff')}
}


$allMediaFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\User\Documents\ScripsPS1\xip\Testes\*   | % {
$content = get-content -Path $_ -Raw
$xml = [xml]$content


    [pscustomobject]@{
    video_audio = $xml.XIP.ContentObject.CustomType # video of audio
    SecurityTag = $xml.XIP.ContentObject.SecurityTag 
    Duration = ($xml.XIP.Generation.Properties.Property | where {$_.PropertyName -eq "Duration"}).value
    Format = $xml.XIP.Bitstream.Filename -replace ".*\.", ""
}
```

When i run:

```
  $allMediaFiles | FT
```

I get this result:

```
video_audio SecurityTag    Duration  Format
----------- -----------    --------  ------
video       U_UserAccess   2M9.686S  mp4   
video       U_UserAccess   2M37.526S mp4   
video       U_UserAccess   5M41.419S mp4   
document    LOADING_BAY_10           eaf   
document    LOADING_BAY_10           eaf   
document    LOADING_BAY_10           eaf   
audio       LOADING_BAY_10 0:11:19   WAV   
audio       LOADING_BAY_10 0:03:24   WAV   
audio       LOADING_BAY_10 0:03:37   WAV   
audio       LOADING_BAY_10 0:23:39   WAV   
document    LOADING_BAY_10           eaf   
document    LOADING_BAY_10           eaf     
audio       LOADING_BAY_10 0:16:46   wav
```

My code to try to convert and sum "Duration":

```
 $allMediaFiles | ? {$_.video_audio -eq "video"} | Group-Object -Property Duration | Select Name | if ($_.Duration -match "M"){ Convert-TimeString -Time $_.Duration -Format 'm\Ms\.fff\S'}
 else {Convert-TimeString -Time $_.Duration -Format "h\:mm\:ss"}}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pipe to an `If` statement, which is the main issue you have in the last part of your question.

Here's what I think gets you the result you're looking for:

The below loops through all of the video results of your object by using `ForEach-Object`. It then uses your `Convert-TimeString` function to convert the Duration values of each item in the collection into a string format that can then be converted to the [timestamp] type.

```
$allMediaFiles | Where-Object { $_.video_audio -eq "video" } | ForEach-Object { 

    if ($_.Duration -match "M") { 
        $_.Duration = [TimeSpan](Convert-TimeString -Time $_.Duration -Format 'm\Ms\.fff\S')
    }
    else {
        $_.Duration = [TimeSpan](Convert-TimeString -Time $_.Duration -Format "h\:mm\:ss")
    }

}
```

The following then uses `Measure-Object` to sum the `TotalSeconds` property of the now `[timestamp]` type properties in your collection, which returns as an integer total value of the total milliseconds for your durations. To get those back into a time format we use `New-TimeSpan` on that result:

```
$Result = New-TimeSpan -Seconds ($allMediaFiles.Duration | Measure-Object -Property TotalSeconds -Sum).Sum
```

Then to display as an hh:mm:ss, we can just use `.tostring()` to turn it back into a string:

```
$Result.ToString()
```

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your quick help. For some reason the Duration property is null. Exception setting "Duration": "The property 'Duration' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set."
At line:2 char:11
+     else {$_.Duration = [TimeSpan](Convert-TimeString -Time $_.Durati ...
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting

Comment: Did you remove the bit where you were doing | select name (and the group-object as well) as these would have removed/changed the properties on the object.